# configure: error: 'parallel' not found

Tags: debian, gnome, theme

Hello I'm trying to install adapta-gtk-theme on Gnome Debian and I've been installing dependencies for 45 minutes, but now I can't find information about this error `configure: error: 'parallel' not found.` I  tried looking 
in apt-cache search for parallel but around 500 packages are available and I'm not sure which one to install and none of them have parallel in the name. Are you familiar with this error or do you know what could be causing the error? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [README](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme/blob/master/README.md), parallel builds require [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is [`parallel`](https://tracker.debian.org/parallel) in Debian.